# How to make a REST request in my case?

Tags: angularjs, rest, http

I am reading a `RESTFUL` API doc and one of the PUT methods requires `request body` to be sent.

The doc mentions

```
PUT /api/v1.2/product/{id}
```

with request body like

```
{
  "name" : "Toy",
  "description" : "Kids toy",
  "price" : 25 
}
```

my current request codes.

```
   $http.put('/api/v1.2/product/' + ID);
```

I am trying to use `Angular http` request to make the call but not sure how to make the request with the request body. Can someone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Comment: The doc also mentions how to pass data: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The angular defines some syntax, you have to main that other wise you won't do anything. You can try is

**JS CODE**

```
   var data = {
     "name" : "Toy",
     "description" : "Kids toy",
     "price" : 25 
   };

    $scope.save = function () {            
        $http.put('/api/v1.2/product/' + ID, data).success(function (data) {

        }).error(function (data) {
            $scope.error = "An Error has occured while Saving customer! " + data;
            $scope.loading = false;
        });
    };
```

**API CODE**

```
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(int ID, Product product)
    {

    }
```

I have written a article into code project [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/832288/CRUD-with-SPA-ASP-NET-Web-API-and-Angular-js). From here you can get full concept of $http get , put, delete.

Answer (score 2):

The data goes in the second parameter to `put`. For example:

```
var data = {
  "name" : "Toy",
  "description" : "Kids toy",
  "price" : 25 
};

$http.put('/api/v1.2/product/' + ID, data)
    .success(function(response, status, headers, config){
        //do something with response here.
    })
    .error(function(response, status, headers, config){
        //handle error here.
        $scope.error_message = response.error_message;
    });
```

For more info, see [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#put)

Answer (score 0):

[$resource](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource) possibly provides a nicer api (though still uses $http under the hood)

Given your data:

```
var data = {
  "name" : "Toy",
  "description" : "Kids toy",
  "price" : 25 
};
```

Setup your resource

```
var Product = $resource('/api/v1.2/product/:id', { 'put': { method:'PUT' } });
```

Then to make a request with it, you just need to:

```
Product.put({ id: ID }, data);
```

If you want to handle a response or errors, just pass the callbacks in too:

```
Product.put({ id: ID }, data, function(data){ }, function(error){ });
```

Check out the documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource

It can do some pretty cool stuff with promises (Not that $http  can't, $resource is just a little nicer IMHO)

It provides GET, POST and DELETE methods by default. PUT is a special case so thats why we needed to specify it above.